# I can't access class parameters inside classmethods within a Cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've recently started trying bot development using discord.py, and I've been struggling with a certain situatio, where I'm using regular classmethods inside of Cogs. Here is an example, where the bot should reply "hello there" to the '-hello' command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.testMessage = "hello there"
    
    @commands.command(name = 'hello')
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await self.sayHello(ctx)

    @classmethod
    async def sayHello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.testMessage)

token = os.getenv("botToken")
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

bot.add_cog(TestCog())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

If I run this code and then use the command "-hello" I get the error message:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'TestCog' has no attribute 'testMessage'
```

I thought this was because regular classmethods maybe don't work inside a Cog, so I also tried to write it like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class TestBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix, intents):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=command_prefix, intents=intents)

        self.testMessage = "hello there"
        self.add_cog(TestCog(self))

    @classmethod
    async def sayHello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.testMessage)

class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command(name = 'hello')
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await self.bot.sayHello(ctx)


token = os.getenv("botToken")
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

bot = TestBot('-', intents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

This also gives the same error. However, if I instead don't use a method, and write this as:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class TestBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix, intents):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=command_prefix, intents=intents)

        self.add_cog(TestCog(self))

class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.testMessage = 'hello there'
    
    @commands.command(name = 'hello')
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.testMessage)


token = os.getenv("botToken")
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)

bot = TestBot('-', intents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

It works [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNZW0.png). It also works in the first two cases I don't reference self, for example `await ctx.send('hello there')` instead of  `await ctx.send(self.testMessage)`.
However, it's a bit cumbersome to not be able to use methods inside commands, so I would go around making the first two scenarios work?

Comment: that's how classmethods work, they don't have access to instance variables. classmethods are not used for literally methods in classes. look up what the classmethod decorator actually does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@classmethod` decorator is not for defining methods in classes. it means when this method is called, we pass the class as the first argument instead of the instance of that class (as we normally do with methods). This means you can use the class and its properties inside that method rather than a specific instance. normal functions inside classes are that classes instance methods (normal/default methods) that you want to actually use

Your code doesn't work because the self is actually the class itself and not an instance (since it's a classmethod). and you cannot access the instance variables since it's not an instance.

To fix this you should just remove the classmethod decorator to make it a normal method of the function

```py
class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.testMessage = "hello there"
    
    @commands.command(name = 'hello')
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await self.sayHello(ctx)

    async def sayHello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.testMessage)
```

Comment: also, may I add, you should follow the python formatting guideline [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)